# Focus listener in JTextField

Tags: java, swing

How to move the cursor from `JTextField1` to `JTextField2` without using `TAB` key.How to use the `FOCUS LISTENER` for this task

Comment: as is, the question makes no sense. Specifically, you can't use a _Listener_ to _transfer_ the focus, it's _reporting_ a transfer after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use the focus listener.  Depending on what you code does, you may be able to use this:

```
field2.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 2):

"requestFocusInWindow()" is probably the Swing API you're looking for.

Here are several examples of several different "focus" related tasks:

[Request Focus inside a Window](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/RequestFocusinsideawindow.htm)

Answer (score 2):

set `Focus` and all workaround isn't easy job in the most complex application, if is there attached `DocumentListener` or `Jtextfield1/JTextField2` had already implemented `FocusListene`r that you have to wrap that inside `invokeLater()` your code for `setFocus` form/to should be

```
    Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            myTextField2.requestFocus();
            myTextField2.setText(myTextField2.getText());
            myTextField2.selectAll();
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
```

very complicated are if you needed move and set `Focus` betweens two or more  [Top-level Coantainers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Answer (score 1):

`field2.requestFocus();` ?
or

```
public boolean requestFocusInWindow()
```